# showing HTML input stream to JSF page

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces

By using XML and XSLT (TRANSFORMATION), I have got HTML code as a stream.

I want to bind that code with the JSF component. I am using MyFaces 2.1.6 implementing JSF 2.0.

Please suggest a way to bind the stream to JSF component.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to `String` and show it in `<h:outputText escape="false">`.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.html}" escape="false" />
```